# Edit form with hidden inputs

Tags: php, forms, edit

I have this simple form.

**a.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?

    echo "
        <form action = 'a2.php' method = 'post'>
            <input type = 'text' name = 'name'>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'SEND' name = 'send'>
        </form>
    ";

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**a2.php**

```
<?

$name = $_REQUEST ['name'];
echo $name;

    echo "
    <form action = 'a2.php' method = 'post'>
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'EDIT' name = 'edit'>
     </form>
    ";

?>
```

How can I keep the value introduced when I click EDIT and i'm back to the first form?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you serious? Any reading of tutorials or beginner guides/books would be a very good start ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: using hidden inputs
on a2.php just put another `<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="{$_POST['name']}" />` after you hit submit on a2.php (BTW for it to go back to a.php, you need to change the form `action="a.php"` on a2.php), a.php will have a `$_POST['hidden_name']`, that will contain the value from the first iteration.

**EDIT**: before you start handling `$_SESSION` variables, first initiate the session before any html output with a `session_start()` function.

Use a superglobal like `$_SESSION` so in your case you would need to fetch the incoming in a2.php `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']` and refer to the `$_SESSION['name']` in your `a.php`. Remember that `$_SESSION['name']` will retain the last assigned value until the the session is terminated, I.e. browser window is closed.

You can read more in http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
Also about `session_start`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: And please point him to the `session_start()` function before you get bombarded with _it doesn't work_ comments ;)

Comment: I should have told it before, I know I can use sessions but the teacher told us that we could use hidden inputs, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 1):

1.creating the hidden inputs in forms by using type="hidden"